# intersection of 2 objects of different types

Tags: python, intersection

i want to take the intersection of:

```
(('e', 13.02338360095244), 
 ('a', 11.820318700775383), 
 ('o', 9.20172171683253), 
 ('s', 7.635081506807498), 
 ('n', 7.547469320471335), 
 ('i', 7.219915745772025), 
 ('r', 6.704927040722877), 
 ('l', 5.650833384211491), 
 ('d', 5.098296599303987), 
 ('t', 4.7109103119848585))
```

and:

```
[('e', 1636), ('n', 991), ('a', 930), ('t', 678), ('o', 677), ('r', 612), ('d', 581), ('i', 507), ('l', 405), ('s', 399)]
```

but these 2 have different types, how do i go about taking the intersection and displaying the amount of elements in the intersection?

Comment: imprtant note: i only care about the keys matching, the values dont have to match up, also the order of the keys doesn't matter

Comment: Simpler example: what do you think the intersection of `(('e', 1),)` and `(('e', 2),)` should *be*? (This question is precisely why there was no built-in support for merging two `dict`s for a very long time. There are several equally valid methods to do so, and the language resisted choosing one.) I assume you want a single tuple whose first element is `'e'`, but what would the second element be?

Comment: please include the desired output

Comment: Can we also assume that no two tuples in a single collection share the same first element (though I'm not sure it really matters)?

Comment: @chepner   i see your point, let me rephrase the problem then:  i want to start with an empty list x = []  then if a key is in both the collections i want to x.append(k). i see how my original question is confusing. i think this should be the correct explanation.

Comment: @timgeb i want a list with the keys that are in both sets.

Comment: `keys = set(x[0] for x in first); result = [x[0] for x in second if x[0] in keys]`

Answer (score 1):

You can you the [intersection of set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp). For example:

```py
a = (('e', 13.02338360095244), 
 ('a', 11.820318700775383), 
 ('o', 9.20172171683253), 
 ('s', 7.635081506807498), 
 ('n', 7.547469320471335), 
 ('i', 7.219915745772025), 
 ('r', 6.704927040722877), 
 ('l', 5.650833384211491), 
 ('d', 5.098296599303987), 
 ('t', 4.7109103119848585))
b = [('e', 1636), ('n', 991), ('a', 930), ('t', 678), ('o', 677), ('r', 612), ('d', 581), ('i', 507), ('l', 405), ('s', 399)]

set(k for k,_ in a).intersection(k for k,_ in b)
```

Output will be `{'i', 'a', 's', 'n', 'r', 'l', 't', 'o', 'd', 'e'}`.